# Python response object returns unexpected utf code points

Tags: python, xml, soap, unicode

I am attempting to retrieve a response in the form of an xml byte string from a web service using the Response library, parse it with an XSLT in memory, and write the output to Teradata using pyodbc. I am using python 3.

Any letter beyond the standard ascii 127 code point appears to come in as two characters. For example ü comes over as Ã¼ into the database.

’ comes over as â and two unprintable characters after it (PAD,and SGCI according to notepad++)

There is also the possibility Kanji characters in the response.

My code:

```
cnxn.pyodbc.connect('mydsn')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

transform = etree.XSLT(etree.fromstring(xsltasstring))
p = etree.XML(response.content)
result_tree = transform(p)
linefeed = '\n'
recordseperator = ','
output_list = str(result_tree).split(linefeed)
insert_sql = 'insert into the_table(.....)'
for item in output_list:
    temp_list = item.split(recordseperator)
    final_list.append(temp_list)
    print(item)
    print(item.encode())
cursor.executemany(insert_sql,final_list)
```

When I look in the database, an example string: ação has been translated to aÃ§Ã£o

In the loop,

```
 print(item) outputs correctly: ação`

 print(final_list) also looks correct: ação

 print(item.encode()) outputs b'a\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
```

`c3,a7,c3,x3 corresponds to Ã§Ã£`. I do not understand what is causing this, or how to fix it.

I would have expected to see something like: `b'a\xe7\xe3o'`

Based on an odbc trace I do see those code points c3,a7, and x3 are passed to the buffer.

The response from the web service does have the `UTF-8` encoding declaration,  and the web service vendor also says the response encoding is `UTF-8.`

Comment: you need to convert the strings youre putting in the database from ascii to utf-8

Comment: @Fire Do you mean Latin-1 when you say ascii?

Comment: As I just said in your previous post, the byte string `b'a\xe7\xe3o'` is the Latin-1 encoding of "ação". The UTF-8 encoding is `b'a\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'`. Do not confuse Unicode code points (`U+E7` for "ç") with the byte values of their physical encoding (`C3 A7` for UTF-8).

Comment: If you take the UTF-8 encoded byte string `b'a\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'` and treat (ie. decode) it as if it was Latin-1, you get "Ã§Ã£". This is because you have a 1:1 correspondence of code points and byte values in Latin-1 – but you only get the first 256 of the 120k Unicode characters.

Comment: In other words: What you have in `item` seems correct. If things go wrong with the DB communication, you need to show an example of inserting an entry into and then fetching it from the DB.

Comment: @lenz. When I query the database and print the result to console, I do get ação back. The ODBC trace seems to show the same bytes for the insert and select.

`SELECT

43 6C 61 73 73 69 66 69 63 61 C3 83 C2 A7 C3 83 Classifica

C2 A3 6F 20 42 72 61 73 69 6C 65 69 72 61 20 64   o Brasileira d`


`INSERT

00 43 6C 61 73 73 69 66 69 63 61 C3 83 C2 A7 C3  Classifica

83 C2 A3 6F 20 42 72 61 73 69 6C 65 69 72 61 20    o Brasileira`

Comment: So that's good news, I guess?

Comment: @lenz It certainly is perplexing, since the data is being stored incorrectly in the database.

Comment: I still fail to see what you is supposed to be incorrect here (but I don't know how to read those traces).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the Teradata 16.20 drivers stopped this problem, but I never was able to figure out exactly why this was happening.